# Do Cysts have any unique abilities?

Tags: killing-floor-2

In the original Killing Floor, every enemy had a unique ability; [Clots](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Clot) could grab and immobilize you, [Gorefasts](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Gorefast) had a sword arm and could sprint, [Scrakes](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Scrake) had chainsaws, [Fleshpounds](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/Fleshpound) ruined your life, etc.

In Killing Floor 2, now, there are a couple *new* types of enemies, one of them being the [Cyst](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Cyst).

However, I can't seem to find any outstanding ability that they have, neither in-game nor documented. On top of that, they don't seem functionally different at all from the updated [Clot](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Alpha_Clot) specimen. Am I overlooking something or do Cysts *really* do nothing special at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, it appears that the reason Cysts have the same abilities that were once unique to Clots is that they *are* Clots, to some extent. More accurately, they are somewhat deformed or failed versions of Clots.

From the [Specimens wikia page](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Specimens_(Killing_Floor_2)), you can see that Cysts and Clots (as well as Slashers) have the *exact* same stats as each other, as well as money and experience rewards for killing them.

This led me to go to the [Slasher wikia page](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=Slasher), where I found the following line:

> However, Slashers are more agile, aggressive and unpredictable **than the other Clot variants.**

From there, I found various references to the fact that Cysts and Slashers are variants of the Clot Specimens, such as [here](http://www.pcgamer.com/killing-floor-2-exclusive-first-look-co-op-fps-horror-with-the-most-advanced-gore-system-ever/2/):

> The Cysts are new, weaker Clot variants—the underdeveloped killer babies of the genetic freak family.

Thus, Cysts do **not** have any unique abilities, as they share the ability to grab and immobilize the player with the other Clot variants. Cysts are, however, unique in the ability to stumble repeatedly while attempting to grab the player, as they are the most unstable variant of the Clots.

Answer (score 0):

They do, in fact, have a special ability explained in the link you provided :

> - Cysts move slowly when docile, and sprint when enraged.
> - On higher difficulties, Cysts have a chance to enrage upon sighting a Player, and have a chance to enrage when shot.
> - **Once enraged, Cysts will never stop sprinting until they are killed.**

They have a speedboost like the Gorefast had in KF. It's not that much of an ability, but after all, they're only cannon fodder.

> The Cyst is a common specimen in Killing Floor 2. It is classified as a lesser enemy, and therefore, cannon fodder. Cysts are generally considered to be the weakest specimens in the game, **whose only purpose is to populate the level**.

Comment: Look at the KF2 Clot's wikia. It says the *exact* same thing about the speed boost.

Comment: Well, your question is  "Am I overlooking something or do Cysts really do nothing special at all?" They do run and grab like the Clot. You need to specify if you want a point by point comparison with the Clot.

Comment: I believe the question itself was pretty clear, though the title may not have been, so I updated it.

Comment: I would suggest to clarify the question. "do Cysts really do nothing special at all" is too broad. Enraging and grabbing is a special ability. Nothing different from the Clot I concede, but still special.